# vc++ 2010 add compiler switch

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, compiler-construction, static-libraries

I am trying to build a library (first time i ever tried that) and the instructions in the documentation are enough for someone who understands how but not for noobs like me.

Here is the what the documentation says 
"
To create a library do the following minimum steps:

- create a “Win32 static library” called “library”,
- add all source files into this project,
- add the symbol “TETLIBRARY” to compile switches.
- build the project.
  "

Ok, I done the first 2 bullet points. There are only 3 source files and I added them. 
creating a win32 static lib was easy enough. 
I have spent the last half hour / fourty-five minutes searching for how to "add a compile switch" and closest I got was adding "TETLIBRARY" to command line in properties and that just returned a "no such file" error

So my question to you lovable square-eyed eggheads is: How do I add the symbol “TETLIBRARY” to compile switches."?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume it means define `TETLIBRARY` as a preprocessor symbol.  To do this:

Open the Project Properties.  Select "All Configurations" in the Configurations drop-down list (at the top left of the dialog).  The navigate to:

Configuration Properties | C/C++ | Preprocessor

You should see something like:

Preprocessor Definitions: `WIN32;<different options>`

Change this to:

Preprocessor Definitions: `TETLIBRARY;WIN32;<different options>`

Close the dialog.  You are done.

The `<different options>` refer to the Debug and Release build options.  If you go back into the dialog you should see that `TETLIBRARY` is defined for both builds.

Comment: Hmm, well there is no error now, which could be a good thing xD
However Its also not outputting a .lib file, which is what the documentation says it will :(
Would a link to the documentation help?
http://tetgen.berlios.de/files/tetgen-manual.pdf

Comment: When you  build something the Output window show you what the compiler did, any errors, and so on.  It usually finishes up with a conclusion.  Something like: `test.vcxproj -> S:\Progs\test\Release\test.exe`.  What do you see?

Comment: I get the feeling I'm having problems cause im on 64bit and this was made in 2009 on 32 bit.
Also I got a bunch of "cannot find or open the PBD file" looking up what that is now. but its not marked as an error.
Finally there is no output line, just a bunch of loads. and im pretty sure this is normal but it exits with code 0 (0x0)

Comment: If it's looking for PDBs and loading stuff it's trying to run the project, not build it.  Which suggests it built OK.  Try the menu Build | Rebuild Solution.  Then you can see what it did with the outputs.

Comment: Good to know, they never told us that at uni. Now, its building just fine and outputting a .exe and That .exe does nothing as far as I can tell.
I should mention that this is someone elses code. My bad for not mentioning that. Its a library that someone else made and I dunno why they dont just give u the damn .lib file and save u the trouble.